# Convert ES6 library back to "working" JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

How do I identify ES6 code?

What is the easiest way to convert/transpile it back to "working" JavaScript?  (More below)

### Background

Two ~EmberJs libraries made the switch to ES6.  Handlebars [did this in v1.1](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/blob/master/release-notes.md).  ember-data [did it in beta.7](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

What format was [ember-data beta.6](http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.0.0-beta.7/ember-data.js) or handlebars 1.0.0 in (that I should now be converting to)?  AMD, CommonJS, ...?

I am using Grunt on this project and understand there are tasks to transpile, I'd accept direction on using Grunt to convert the ES6 stuff back to whatever format it should be in.  I'm equally happy to just convert it with some tool once and try to figure out how to handle ES6 later.

Each time I tried to upgrade it wasn't clear that a whole new format/syntax was gumming up the works until I (googled for and) read the changelog.  Is it expected that your Grunt setup automatically converts ES6 whenever it's found?

Comment: I'll just mention that there **is** no ES6 yet. There are [*in-progress, working drafts*](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts) of a spec, but they are still *work in progress* and will change prior to the spec being finalized. (There are, for example, [currently 401 open bugs against the ES6 drafts](https://bugs.ecmascript.org/buglist.cgi?query_format=specific&order=relevance+desc&bug_status=__open__&product=Draft+for+6th+Edition&content=).) ES6 is getting close, but we're not there yet.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few transpilers out there to go from ES6 to ES5 or lower, but Ember.js uses the [ES6 Module Transpiler](https://github.com/square/es6-module-transpiler) in their code. It doesn't support all ES6 syntax, just the module syntax.

But like TJ Crowder said, ES6 isn't final yet. I tend to stay away from using ES6 syntax when interacting with other libraries just to avoid any issues. I would recommend using the compiled, ES5 version of the library if you can.

Comment: Thanks and sorry I didn't see your response until now.  I don't really want to use ES6 and thought it was strange that  when I downloaded the newer version of a lib it broke my build.  It seems like they are putting out different builds now in different formats.  I still don't know how to tell by looking at the source (or using a tool) if something is an ES6 module, AMD module, etc.  It also looks like the build that ember-data put out just works now, so maybe it was just a bad release?